# find dot in CSV and replace with found names in Active Directory group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a TXT file and converted it to CSV.

Now I want to have a script which:

- Look in `UserID` column and look if there is a name with dot in it (ex: `xyz.aaa`). The names with dot in them are not UserID but they are Group.
- Then it should look for them in AD.
- Then replace the found names in the same CSV file.

Find all CNs in TXT file and list them in CSV File:

```
Select-String -Path $TXTFile  -Pattern 'CN=(.*?),' -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } | 
    select @{L="UserID"; E={$_}} |
    Export-CSV $CSVFile1 -Delimiter ";"
```

what I tried and it does not work, which definately wrong is:

look for `.` in `UserID` column which are Groups, then look for them in AD. Replace the members in Groupnames.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $CSVFile1 | ForEach-Object {  
    (Get-Content $_.UserID).Replace('.','Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$_.UserID" -Recursive | Select Name') | Out-File $_.UserID
}
```

Comment: ... still your EXL comparison task?  ... where does this TXT file comes from? Aren't you able to get those information already prepared/suited for your needs?

Comment: it has nothing to do with EXL. i got txt file, and could convert it to CSV. just do not know how to search for '.'/Groups and reaplce it with the members.

Comment: If you're looking for a "pattern" you can use regular expressions  .... [-match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)  ...  if you already have a CSV file you should use Import-CSV instead of Get-Content!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick I think

```
$ProcessedList = Import-Csv -Path $CSVFile1 -Delimiter ';' | 
    Select-Object -Property *,
    @{
        Name='ProcessedUserID';
        Expression={
            if ($_.UserID -match '\.') {
                (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.UserID | 
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName) -join ','
            }
            else {
                $_.UserID
            }
        }
    }
$ProcessedList
$ProcessedList | Export-CSV -Path 'Whatever' -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Thanks alot. it helped me alot but from the time you posted the answer i am looking for a way to store the results of AD in $ProcessedUserID and export $_.UserID and $ProcessedUserID in csv but i am not successful. because what I get from AD is array {A,B,C,...} but I want them in CSV...in CSV I get UserID and ProcessedUSerID in one Column.

Comment: I recommend for you to urgently take the time to learn the basics of Powershell. You're asking basic questions that you wouldn't have to ask if you knew the fundamentals. I added the code to export the list in a CSV file.